# How to pass multiple information from a listView to another activity using the OnclickListener method

Tags: java, android

I have a small problem with my application. I want to pass it the data stored in my listView and when I do setOnItemClickListener it doesn't send the stored data. Attached is part of my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
ArrayList<String> list;
Button btAdd;
EditText etName, etAge, etDescription;
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    etAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
    etDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDescription);
    btAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btGuardar);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvList);
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener((adapterView, view, i, l) -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DataActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Name",list);
        intent.putExtra("Age", list);
        intent.putExtra("Description", list);
        startActivity(intent);
    });
    btAdd.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        String names=etName.getText().toString();
        String ages=etAge.getText().toString();
        String description= etDescription.getText().toString();
        String stringFormatted = String.format(names,ages,description);
        list.add(stringFormatted);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    });
}
```

}

public class DataActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView tvName,tvAge,tvDescription;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_data);
    tvName = findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    tvAge = findViewById(R.id.tvAge);
    tvDescription= findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    extras.getString("Name");
    extras.getString("Age");
    extras.getString("Description");
}
```

}

Comment: listview is deprecated, but regardless, what exactly is the problem ? you are currently passing in `list` three times, so your actual question is how to get items at a specific position, or... ?

Comment: No, the explanation may have caused confusion.

I have a list that stores data from 3 EditText. What I'm trying to do is for each item in the list, when I do onItemClickListener, the stored data travels to activity 2.

Comment: Your use of `String.format(names,ages,description);` is questionable - what do you think that does ?

Answer (score 1):

You're adding the entire array three times in the extras as a Serializable here:

```
intent.putExtra("Name",list);
intent.putExtra("Age", list);
intent.putExtra("Description", list);
```

But here, you're trying to get a String:

```
extras.getString("Name");
extras.getString("Age");
extras.getString("Description");
```

Either send a String and get a String, or send a Serializable and get a Serializable.

Comment: Thanks for the information Sharp, but I would like if you could exemplify with code, how do you think would be the most efficient option to pass the data of a list. Thanks

Comment: If you need the data individually (name/age/description), you can create fields in the MainActivity and store data into them, then pass each one of them separately. So at the top of your activity you have "String name; String age; String description;", in btAdd click listener, you assign the info to those three fields, and then in intent.putExtra() you put each one separately (e.g., intent.putExtra("Name", name); intent.putExtra("Age", age); intent.putExtra("Description", description). Is that clear enough?

Comment: You could also instead create a Serializable (or preferably Parcelable) class such as "class Person(name, age, description)" to encapsulate this data as it is probably related, and then you can instantiate it in btAdd listener (person = Person(name, age, description), and then pass it as "intent.putExtra("Person", person);", and get it as "extras.getExtra("Person") as Person". This is probably the cleaner approach if you want to make your code nicer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
     arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener((adapterView, view, i, l) -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DataActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Name",list.get(i).split("#123#")[0]);
        intent.putExtra("Age", list.get(i).split("#123#")[1]);
        intent.putExtra("Description", list.get(i).split("#123#")[2]);
        startActivity(intent);
    });
    btAdd.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        String names=etName.getText().toString();
        String ages=etAge.getText().toString();
        String description= etDescription.getText().toString();
        String stringFormatted = names+"#123#"+ages+"#123#"+description;
        list.add(stringFormatted);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    });
```

But this not perfect way i made it just to show you how can work, because in this case List should have one item inside, i made it 3 items merged by #123#..

**So in your case you need to use custom GridView and pass 3 lists to it..**

I mean

```
List for Names
List for Ages
List for Description
```